# Plugin for zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2

$url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

```
    if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
      return false;
    }
    return true;I need to  connect plugin CheckDomain which loaded on pre dispatch with all modules except Admin.
```

Plugin is a class CheckDomain which could be called as a function `CheckDomain()` when it's called in that way it checks is domain equal to "test.example.com"

```
<?php 
namespace Application\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\FlashMessenger;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Forward;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Layout;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Params;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\PostRedirectGet;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Redirect;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Url;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

 class CheckDomainPlugin extends AbstractPlugin{

  public function checkdomain()
  {

        $url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

        if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)){
            return false;
       }
        return true;
    }  
}
```

I call it for every controller except Admin, but I need to use it once.

I mean is it possible to load automatically plugin for all modules axcept admin

Comment: can you please more specific what you are trying to achieve? i don't get the exactly question on your post. when you create a controller plugin it is available in every module controller.

Comment: I want to load plugin automatically for all modules except admin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you wish to "hook up" into every module you should read the zf2 documentation about `MVC Events` and the `EventManager` class.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html#the-mvcevent

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.event-manager.event-manager.html

Here is a small example for your `Application/Module.php`

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $application =  $e->getApplication();
    $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
    $eventManager = $application->getEventManager();
    $sharedManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();

    // DISPATCH EVENT
    $sharedManager->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function( MvcEvent $e) use ($serviceManager) {

        $controller      = $e->getTarget();
        $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
        $moduleNamespace = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));

        // this is the first segment from the module namespace
        // if the Admin Namespace is something like this Admin/Controller/...

        if( $moduleNamespace != 'Admin' ) {

            $CheckDomainPlugin = $serviceManager->get('ControllerPluginManager')->get('CheckDomainPlugin');
            // do something
        }
    }, 50 );
}
```

Comment: It is almost what I wanted! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a plugin, or any service, they will be *available* to all modules within the application. If there are areas in which the plugin should not be used then don't call it!

If I actually understand your problem; I would use an event listener for this. If you listen 'on dispatch' you can exclude all the admin controllers if you give them a unique  interface.

```
 // Module.php
 public function onBootstrap($event)
 {
   $application = $event->getApplication();
   $eventManager = $application->getEventManager()->getSharedManager();

   $eventManager->attach(
     'Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 
     'dispatch', 
     function($e) {
       $target = $e->getTarget(); // The dispatched controller

       if ($controller instanceof AdminControllerInterface) {
         return;
       }
       // Do something here
     }
   );
 }
```

Comment: It is almost what I wanted! Thanks